# axios post promise returning error disallowing accessing result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fastapi

I am new to using JS frameworks. So I have an authentication backend built in FastAPI using Python.  It handles creating a JWT access token for a user to interact with my React front-end.

Here is the client I've created to call that API (not sure if Client is the proper term in JS).

```js
export const authApi = {
  /**
   * Retrieves the JWT access token of registered user.
   * @param {string} username - Username of attempting user.
   * @param {string} password - Password of attempting user.
   */
  async logInGetToken(username, password) {
    const params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append('username', username);
    params.append('password', password);
    return axios.post(`${apiUrl}/api/v1/login/access-token`, params);
  },
  /**
   * Pings authentication server to determine whether access token is valid.
   * @param {*} token - API token provided via Authentication API.
   */
  async isActiveToken(token) {
    return axios.post(`${apiUrl}/api/v1/login/test-token`, authHeaders(token));
  },
  ...
}
```

I am now trying to build a validation handler to access whether the access token is still not expired. Here is the code I've generated for this:

```js
const isAuthenticated = () => {
    return authApi.isActiveToken(
        localStorage.getItem('token')
    ).then(res => {
        console.log(res)
        if (res.status > 400) {
            return false
        }
        return true
    })
}
```

I have put a `console.log` statement inside the promise executor that will log the data returned from my API call.  However, this log is never returned, rather I see on the console:

`POST http://localhost:8000/api/v1/login/test-token 401 (Unauthorized)`

I am also a bit new to the concept of Promises, but this seemingly never enters my promise `then` block.  Any tips?

Thank you!

---

If its helpful, here is where `isAuthenticated` is being used:

```js
const AuthenticatedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
        isAuthenticated()
            ? <Component {...props} />
            : <Redirect to='/login' />
    )} />
);

const UnauthenticatedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
        !isAuthenticated()
            ? <Component {...props} />
            : <Redirect to='/' />
    )} />
);
```

Comment: Hi, the problem seems to be the token you are sent, just to confirm you can do console.log(localStorage.getItem('token')) and check if you care sending what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errors will trigger the catch block on the promise chain rather than the first argument of the then block.

```
const isAuthenticated = () => {
  return authApi.isActiveToken(localStorage.getItem('token')).then(
    (res) => {
      console.log(res);
      if (res.status > 400) {
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    },
    (error) => {
      return false;
    }
  );
};
```

Or as a separate catch block:

```
const isAuthenticated = () => {
  return authApi
    .isActiveToken(localStorage.getItem('token'))
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      if (res.status > 400) {
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      return false;
    });
};
```

Another possibility using async/await, I tend to prefer using this as it's easier to read, but it can be confusing because it disguises itself as looking more like synchronous code.

```
const isAuthenticated = async () => {
  try {
    await authApi
    .isActiveToken(localStorage.getItem('token'))
    return true;
  } catch (error) {
    return false;
  }
};
```

---

Edit: Here's how to modify your code to allow for the asynchronous nature of the isAuthenticated call. The reason you were running into an issue is because Promises are truthy by nature and you were performing a ternary operation off of a Promise rather than the value from a promise.

Asynchronous code works by immediately returning a promise that is essentially a value to be. At some point, the promise will result in a value, but you can't count on it being a value in synchronous code, so you have to set a state that will let your component know what the value ends up being.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const isAuthenticated = async () => {
  try {
    await authApi.isActiveToken(localStorage.getItem('token'));
    return true;
  } catch (error) {
    return false;
  }
};

const AuthenticatedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    isAuthenticated().then((authenticated) => {
      setAuthenticated(authenticated);
    });
  });
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => {
        return authenticated === undefined ? (
          'Loading...'
        ) : authenticated ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to="/" />
        );
      }}
    />
  );
};

const UnauthenticatedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    isAuthenticated().then((authenticated) => {
      setAuthenticated(authenticated);
    });
  });
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => {
        return authenticated === undefined ? (
          'Loading...'
        ) : !authenticated ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to="/" />
        );
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this.. which approach would you consider to be more elegant? I really appreciate it

Comment: When using promise chaining, I typically end up using a separate catch, but that's just personal preferences. I usually use async await instead. I'll add that to answer.

Comment: Awesome. Much appreciated... unfortunately, I'm still hitting the error above; my request is not returning `false` rather I just see a bad POST request in the console.. Anything else I'm missing or can provide?

Comment: Added some more context above

Comment: isAuthenticated will return a promise of type boolean.

Comment: Right, but if I pass invalid credentials, I get a `400`+ response and its still allowing me to access my `AuthenticatedRoute`

Comment: Sorry, maybe my understanding of Promises is weak, just trying to understand.  I really appreciate your insight!

Comment: A promise is a truthy value which is why it's going through anyway

Comment: Makes sense.. how can I modify my code to handle the needs to `AuthenticatedRoute`?

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for making this edit.. this is a major step in the right direction for me... one last thing: i am hitting a compilation error on the code above saying: `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression` which is happening at `authenticated === undefined`

Comment: That's fixed now. I had forgotten to put `return` in front of that line so the value wasn't being returned.